Record online conversation between me and the client using Javascript
Is it possible to record our online conversation with a client using Javascript or Angular?
Record not only my voice but as well as my client's voice.
I have tried MediaRecorder but it seems to record only my voice and does not include my client's voice. Therefore, I can't really record our whole conversation.

Does this answer your question? Record internal audio of a website via javascript. Though it didn't work it would still be good to share what you tried (or a minimal recreation, if you don't own it) as it may just be missing something.

@l3l_aze sorry but it does not answer my question. I have no problem recording my audio when I am the one speaking. The problem is that, I can't capture the audio of the person I am with in the video chat when he/she speaks.

Ah, sorry; IDK what planet I was on during that, lol. It looks like what you would need is the WebRTC API and the MediaStream API and some of the other Media-related methods the MediaStream page links to. Easier to use some method of recording from your PC itself, though obviously not as cool.

Well  it is possible using webrtc itself or through a library
In the link below there is my webrtc demo that can record local and remote video/audio using javascript and rtcmulticonnection library with also recordrtc library.
You must check the box recording before starting the webrtc call,
then press open room to start as a local user. Then for remote user click the QueryString URL appearing once the room is created.
after you did the test click stop recording.
https://vrobbi-webrtc-demo.glitch.me/?calltype=video-audio
you have to look at the code below in order to record the video call
in the html code of the page.
if (chkRecordConference.checked === true) {
      btnStopRecording.style.display = 'inline-block';
      recordingStatus.style.display = 'inline-block';

      var recorder = connection.recorder;
      if (!recorder) {
        recorder = RecordRTC([event.stream], {
          type: 'video'
        });
        recorder.startRecording();
        connection.recorder = recorder;
      }
      else {
        recorder.getInternalRecorder().addStreams([event.stream]);
      }

      if (!connection.recorder.streams) {
        connection.recorder.streams = [];
      }

      connection.recorder.streams.push(event.stream);
      recordingStatus.innerHTML = 'Recording ' + connection.recorder.streams.length + ' streams';
    }

    if (event.type === 'local') {
      socketconnection.socket.on('disconnect', function () {

        if (!connection.getAllParticipants().length) {
          location.reload();
        }
      });
    }


  };

  var recordingStatus = document.getElementById('recording-status');
  var chkRecordConference = document.getElementById('record-entire-conference');
  var btnStopRecording = document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording');
  btnStopRecording.onclick = function () {
    var recorder = connection.recorder;
    if (!recorder) return alert('No recorder found.');
    recorder.stopRecording(function () {
      var blob = recorder.getBlob();
      invokeSaveAsDialog(blob);

      connection.recorder = null;
      btnStopRecording.style.display = 'none';
      recordingStatus.style.display = 'none'; // stop
      chkRecordConference.parentNode.style.display = 'inline-block';
    });
  };


While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
